# Bootstrap Alert: Dismiss button showing incorrectly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm messing around with Bootstrap and I *think* I've done everything listed on their page about the Alert. But my close-button just looks like a big fat grey square with an X in it.

Any idea what I'm missing?

https://codepen.io/Slagon/pen/NWORGpv

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
</ul>

<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Alert!</strong> 
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you accually want?  How your close button look like?

Comment: It should be a wide cross on a transparent background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `close` class in the button. Just change it to `btn-close`

Here is a working demo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
</ul>

<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Alert!</strong> 
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true" >&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! Yeah that did the trick. Their official docs only use class="close", idk why. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/

Comment: you are referencing Bootstrap v4 docs while you are using Bootstrap v5.3. Here is the correct link [Bootstrap v5.3 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/alerts/#dismissing)

Comment: That makes sense :D just googled the docs and took the first one.

Comment: And you will need to remove the span inside the button because the icon is being duplicated

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
</ul>

<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Alert!</strong> 
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
       
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this CODE to make  Bootstrap ALERT working with Close Button -

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">3</li>
</ul>

<div class="alert alert-custom alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <strong>Alert!</strong> 
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```